# Java classes which depend on each other

Tags: java, oop

I'm learning the Play framework. I'm cunfused about three classes which represent a warehouse-stock item-product data model:

```
public class Product {
  public Long ean; 
  public String name;
  public String description;
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}

public class Warehouse {
  public String name;
  public List<StockItem> stock = new ArrayList<>(); 
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}

public class StockItem {
  public Warehouse warehouse; 
  public Product product; 
  public Long quantity;
  public String toString() {
    return String.format("%d %s", quantity, product);
  }
}
```

Class *Warehouse* depends on class *StockItem*. Class *StockItem* depends on class *Product* and *Warehouse*.

How to understand this kind of relationship?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Warehouse` is a container class and it has many items - `StockItem`'s. So `Warehouse` knows about `StockItem` and every `StockItem` knows what `Warehouse` it belongs to.
Something like:

```
Warehouse warehouse = new Warehouse();
StockItem item1 = new StockItem();
item1.warehouse = warehouse;
warehouse.stock.add(item1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Warehouse contains many StockItems. Although checking is not done, StockItem can only belongs to one Warehouse. (Warehouse 1 --- many StockItem)

StockItem is of specific Product (it can't be 2 types at the same time!!!). (StockItem many -- 1 Product: note that you can have a lot of StockItem objects of the same Product)

Answer (score 1):

> ***Class Warehouse depends on class StockItem. Class StockItem depends on class Product and Warehouse.***

The implementation of `Warehouse` mentions `StockItem`:

```
public class Warehouse {
    ...
    public List<StockItem> stock = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

thus it *depends* on that class. Without `StockItem` you wouldn't be able to compile and use a `Warehouse`. That's how the relation is to be understood.

Same goes for `StockItem` vs `Product` and `Warehouse`:

```
public class StockItem {
    ...
    public Warehouse warehouse;
    public Product product; 
    ...
}
```

Without `Product` you wouldn't be able to compile and use a `StockItem`.

Comment: "Without StockItem you wouldn't be able to compile" -> Maybe you should mention that without the **class** `StockItem` you can't compile your code. Because you can compile without an object of `StockItem`. Same goes for your last line: "Without `Product`" -> without the **class** `Product`